# limit the size of the list in jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/ with the static java script array as a data to auto complete the text field. 
 is there any way so that i can limit the size of the list for auto completion?

Comment: what criteria are you going to use to limit your list? I assume you could set data to a function that contains your data and limits the results, but it begs the question of how you do that

Comment: I've a list of 10000 items to search for. Is there another better method to do that?

Comment: You have 10000 items in a static javascript array? Yikes - seems like it would be much more performant in a database - is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the **max** option.

See here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete

Comment: is this the same plugin the OP is referring to?

Comment: Yup, please see: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: wouldn't it be the maxItemsToShow option then? I'm just asking - I haven't used this option before.

Comment: If you go to the URL I posted and click the options tab you will see the **max** option. "Limit the number of items in the select box. Is also sent as a "limit" parameter with a remote request."

Comment: I must be losing my mind - I swear when I was browsing the options from the Google link she posted there was a maxItemsToShow option, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't crazy - I was just looking somewhere else: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/source/browse/doc/jquery.autocomplete.txt

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/  and http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete are different right?

Comment: As I can see here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ It's not different, or maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I think the code on Google is based on that plugin, but someone else has been checking changes into it there by a different developer, so it might not be the same anymore.

Comment: You may be right. @hemanth: try what **kinakuta** said, it should work if mine is not.

Comment: Maybe at some point there was a `max` option but it's not there now